# How to write a character that lost his passion , his purpose that he had for his goal after he achives it and how to revive his passion?

Tags: fiction, style, characters, plot, character-development

So that character is like any typical sports anime character who loved to play cricket a lot and fortunately was gifted and lucky enough to become a big name in world of cricket but with time during his journey from a kid to professional cricketer he lost that love , the thrill , excitement for game and it only became a game of numbers  where the only thing he cared was to score more and more runs which can result in bringing more and more money
But with time i want him to return to that passion ,love feeling he had for this game but at the same time i want to him to retain his competitiveness, a attitude as world top while maintaining a balance between classic team sports stuff and hunger for victory and achivements

But i am not sure how to write him , his persona , the circumstances which whill results in these events etc

As this is about how people with time lose their purpose, passion they had for their goal once they reach their and it only becomes a sort of obligation for them

Any other adivices and refrence material would be appreciated too

Answer (score 1):

It is a relatively common theme for a character to become successful in their field but lose youthful passion in the process ([Citizen Kane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen_Kane) is one prominent example).

How we can force the character to reconnect with this passion?

First, there is a need of some kind of professional or personal crisis, so the character can realize that they lost they way and need to make changes. After that crisis had struck, there are two common ways out of it:

1. Mature mentor. The character in crisis finds a mentor who sets them on the right way;
2. Young protege. The character sees the passion that they lost in a younger character (or set of characters, ex. [The Mighty Ducks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mighty_Ducks_(film))) and help themselves by helping that young character.